# Why the output is blank when added a name in Where clause with AND?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below query is running fine with good output -

```
SELECT  RadioFinalizedBy, ProcedureType, DATEDIFF(HOUR, ScanCompleteDate,RadioFinalisedDate) As 'Date Diff', 
        ScanCompleteDate, RadioFinalisedDate
FROM    VW_RisOrderTable
WHERE   YEAR(ScanCompleteDate) = 2023
AND     MONTH(ScanCompleteDate) = 03
AND     DATEDIFF(HOUR, ScanCompleteDate,RadioFinalisedDate) > 24;
```

But as soon as I add one more 'AND' to it, the query runs but the output is blank.

Adding one more AND -

```
SELECT  RadioFinalizedBy, ProcedureType, DATEDIFF(HOUR, ScanCompleteDate,RadioFinalisedDate) As 'Date Diff', 
        ScanCompleteDate, RadioFinalisedDate
FROM    VW_RisOrderTable
WHERE   YEAR(ScanCompleteDate) = 2023
AND     MONTH(ScanCompleteDate) = 03
AND     DATEDIFF(HOUR, ScanCompleteDate,RadioFinalisedDate) > 24
AND     RadioFinalizedBy = 'Yasser Mahfouz';
```

There are records with the above condition but still, the output is blank.

Even when I run the below simple query, the output is still blank.

```
SELECT * FROM VW_RisOrderTable WHERE RadioFinalizedBy = 'Yasser Mahfouz';
```

I am using SQL SERVER. Please help.

Comment: Copy the value from a cell that you think contains that name. Perhaps there's more whitespace than you think.

Comment: Try `WHERE LTRIM(UPPER(RadioFinalizedBy)) LIKE 'YASSER%'` and see what you get.

Comment: It's possible that your data may contain some "hidden" characters (ie. non-standard characters that don't necessarily show if you just do a select on your data in SQL Management Studio).  If you do just SELECT * FROM VW_RisOrderTable and you see "Yasser Mahfouz" as a possible value in the "RadioFinalizedBy" column, then I'd suggest that you definitely do have some funny characters hidden in your data.  Otherwise, you may have a case-sensitive collation on your database, and the upper/lower case letter values do not exactly match

Comment: FYI, you should really be using date ranges for your `WHERE`. Syntax like `YEAR(ScanCompleteDate) = 2023` isn't SARGable, meaning your (poor) data engine will need to scan the *entire* table. Use `>=` and `<` logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM VW_RisOrderTable WHERE RadioFinalizedBy = 'Yasser Mahfouz';
```

If above query is returning no rows then it's there is no rows with the given condition. First check the spelling again carefully. If it's same then you might have extra character at the end or beginning try below query to rule out this:

```
SELECT * FROM VW_RisOrderTable WHERE RadioFinalizedBy like '%Yasser%Mahfouz%';
```

Comment: Thanks, Adding  '%Yasser%Mahfouz%'  helped.

Comment: @Atif that is not a solution. You won't be able to use indexes when querying with `LIKE %`, it just shows that the data indeed can be found. Again, there's likely (zero-width) whitespace in your data. Either remove that, or include it in your query.